# java xml parsing between tags

Tags: java, xml, parsing

What im trying to do is parse xml through java. and i only want a snippet of text from each tag for example.

xml example

```
<data>\nSome Text :\n\MY Spectre around me night and day. Some More: Like a wild beast
guards my way.</data>

<data>\nSome Text :\n\Cruelty has a human heart. Some More: And Jealousy a human face
</data>
```

so far i have this

```
NodeList ageList = firstItemElement.getElementsByTagName("data");
Element ageElement =(Element)ageList.item(0);
NodeList textAgeList = ageElement.getChildNodes();
out.write("Data : " + ((Node)textAgeList.item(0)).getNodeValue().trim());
```

im trying to just get the "Some More:....." part i dont want the whole tag
also im trying to get rid of all the \n

Comment: What specifically is not working?

Comment: i edited it sorry i wasnt clear i dont want the whole tag just from "Some More:"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take all of the element text and use regular expressions to capture the relevant parts.

Comment: Look for the package java.util.regex in the API doc. There´s all you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not restricted to the standard DOM API, you could try to use [jOOX](http://code.google.com/p/joox/), which wraps standard DOM. Your example would then translate to:

```
// Use jOOX's jquery-like API to find elements and their text content
for (String string : $(firstItemElement).find("data").texts()) {

  // Use standard String methods to replace content
  System.out.println(string.replace("\\n", ""));
}
```